# When calling batch script inside Jenkins file doesn't get the values after asterisk

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When calling a batch script inside Jenkins file it doesn't catch/read the value after asterik `*`.

Below are the few lines of my batch code:

```
SET HOUSE=GREENVILLA
SET NUMBER=10
SET HOUSE_NAME=%HOUSE%-%NUMBER%.*.y
```

I only see that `HOUSE_NAME` is set to `GREENVILLA-10.*.y` instead of `GREENVILLA-10.44.6.y`.

The actual path is `\\servername\c\house\name` containing the particular file `greenvilla-10.44.6.y`. I expect `greenvilla-10.44.6.y` being assigned to environment variable `HOUSE_NAME`.

Batch file coding is a new thing for me. I'm not sure about missing some basic things here.

Comment: why do you think `*` should expand to `44.6`?

Comment: Where / from what type of data source are you attempting to extract the missing elements of the  house number from for assignment to the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was I have to replace/remove any extra characters(space,*), when passing an input. I had a special character(") passed in with the number,where batch thought thats the end of the path and didn't give me the other values.
used `Inputval = Inputval.replaceAll("\\W", "")` before passing the value to the batch script in jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 1):

The *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` processing a batch file does not replace argument strings containing a wildcard by all files/folders found in file system matching the wildcard pattern as Linux shell interpreters do, except the argument string containing the wildcard is enclosed in `'`. There must be used code in batch file to get file/folder names matching a wildcard pattern.

```
set "HOUSE=GREENVILLA"
set "NUMBER=10"
set "HOUSE_NAME="
for %%I in ("\\servername\c\house\name\%HOUSE%-%NUMBER%.*.y") do set "HOUSE_NAME=%%I"
if defined HOUSE_NAME echo "%HOUSE_NAME%"
```

The last found non-hidden file in directory `\\servername\c\house\name` matching the wildcard pattern `GREENVILLA-10.*.y` is assigned to environment variable `HOUSE_NAME` with full path because of having specified the wildcard pattern with a folder path.

What is the last found file matching the wildcard pattern is determined by the file system. NTFS returns a list of files matching a pattern different to FAT16, FAT32 and exFAT drives. However, I suppose the directory contains always only one file matching the wildcard pattern.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`